# Transmit video and extra data with Gstreamer RTSP

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I am streaming my laptop's webcamera (Ubuntu) with this:

`gst-rtsp-launch '( v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=320,height=240 ! videoconvert ! queue ! x265enc tune="zerolatency" byte-stream=true bitrate=80 ! rtph265pay name=pay0 pt=96 )'`

As I understand RTSP should be able to transmit extra information? For example, CCTV from camera and weather temperature.

How could I implement this? It probably wont be terminal one-liner, but a script, right?

P.S. - in what units bitrate is measured? I calculated ~97 kbps with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rtpklvdepay and rtpklvpay to add extra metadata.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpklvdepay.html?gi-language=c
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpklvpay.html?gi-language=c

x265enc Bitrate value is in kbits.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/x265/index.html?gi-language=c#properties

Best regards

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to make this video transmission only one way? I am testing radio equipment which is only half duplex, so I can only transmit from it. Would RTSP via UDP be only one way? Or does it still require RX and TX?